# conditional jquery by checking class

Tags: jquery

I cant think straight today, can someone show me the correction that I cannot find right now? I realize im doing something silly I just cannot find. Basically the second function should close the box, but its not working at all.

```
if (!$('div').hasClass('active')) {
   $("span").click(function () {
       $("div").stop().animate({ height: "360px" });
       $("div").addClass('active');
});
}

if ($('div').hasClass('active')) {
   $("span").click(function () {
       $("div").animate({ height: "0px" });
       $("div").removeClass('active');
});
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9xqWF/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are binding multiple event handlers based on a condition, rather than binding one event handler and checking the condition within the handler:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    if($('div').hasClass('active'))
        $("div").animate({ height: "0px" }).removeClass('active');
    else
        $("div").stop().animate({ height: "360px" }).addClass('active');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/BW8LM/

Comment: While I agree with your comments on simplifying the click handler; This still can't really be what the OP wants to do - those inner selectors are applied to every single div everywhere.  More context on those selectors is certainly needed. (see my comments in another answer)

Comment: I agree with giving mark on text in a production like situation, but I believe OP was just getting a proof of concept working. That's why I answered the way that I did. Assuming otherwise it's just that; assuming.

Comment: I just figured it was worth pointing out. (before tomorrow's question is "why do all my divs disappear?")  Given the structure of the example, I think OP thinks there's a lot more context then there is...  so it's worth pointing out sans-second-parameter all selectors apply to the whole DOM.

Comment: haha good point. Fillip was right I was just trying to through up something on JSFiddle to have something working quickly. But you do raise a good point that if I was a newbie just not knowing what I was doing I may come back with a "why are all my divs acting weird now" question. I'll make sure to clarify that in the future. Thanks again guys

Answer (score 2):

Your `if` statements are executed just once and as only one of the conditions can be true, you will have just one handler which won't do what you expect, you should move the logic to your `click` handler:

```
var $div = $('div');
$("span").click(function () {
    var h = $div.toggleClass('active')
                .hasClass('active') ? '0px' : '360px';
    $div.stop().animate({ height: h });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your event should be triggered on click, the way you have it, it checks for the class `active` just once, and then defines 1 click function (you only need 1). So try this:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    if (!$('div').hasClass('active')) {
        $("div").stop().animate({ height: "360px" }).addClass('active');    
    } else {
        $("div").animate({ height: "0px" }).removeClass('active');
    }
});
```

**[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/darkajax/9x3Qb/)**

Answer (score 1):

You never add the second .click-event because the condition `$('div').hasClass('active')`is not guilty at loading your page...

Answer (score 1):

You need to contextualize your inner calls to jQuery, you are calling them on ALL divs not just the `'active'` ones.

```
   $("div").stop().animate({ height: "360px" });
   $("div").addClass('active');
```

these lines are not specific to a div.  without knowing exactly what you need to do I don't know what the right value is here, but probably higher up you need something like this:

```
if ($('div').hasClass('active')) {
   var myDiv = this;
   $("span").click(function () {
```

furthermore this `span` isn't contextualized either which span, one in the `div`? you could do:

```
   $("span", this).click(function () {
```